# How to display pagination on twig template

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, pagination, twig

This is how the pagination on the controller works

```
 /**
     *@Route("/rating/{page}",name="testing")
     */
    public function pagesAction($page,Request $request)
    {
        // retrieve GET variables
        $pageNumber = $request->query->get('pageNumber');
        $pageSize = $request->query->get('pageSize');

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

                $results = $qb->add('select', 'p')
                    ->add('from', 'GabrielUploadBundle:Post p')
                    ->add('where', 'p.upvotes > 100')
                    ->add('orderBy', 'p.createdAt ASC')
                    ->setMaxResults($pageSize)
                    ->setFirstResult($pageSize * ($pageNumber - 1))
                    ->getQuery();


                return $this->render('GabrielLayoutBundle:Worldpage:content_loop.html.twig',array('posts'=>$results->getResult())); 
    }
```

now I only have to pass the pageNumber and pageSize for the URL (it works so far)

> /rating/front?pageNumber=1&pageSize=3

All I need to know is how to display the results like this 
[image: pagination]

I've been struggling with this step since I don't know how to calculate the number of results and how to get the "next " and previous buttons to work

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at **[KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle)**.

It's one of the **[TOP 10%](http://symfony.com/blog/the-30-most-useful-symfony-bundles-and-making-them-even-better)** most used bundles out there.

The bundle provides overrideable [default templates](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/tree/master/Resources/views/Pagination) for rendering the pagination buttons and is very easy to integrate into your project.

If you don't want to use the bundle ... it's source code is definitely a good place to look for inspiration.

---

Your current implementation lacks a second upfront query to get the **total number** of posts.

Without knowing the total number of posts ... you won't be able to determine the number of buttons to show.